# Проблема с DragLeave

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Когда делаю `Drag` для элемента и если навести его на место где нельзя его дропнуть, то генерируется событие `DragLeave`, как будто перестакивание завершено. Но по сути я могу не отпуская кнопку дальше тянуть элемент и положить его в другом месте. В общем мне нужно как-то узнать что именно пользователь завершил дроп или отменил его. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Leave означает что область покинута, и окно не должно "сопровождать" обьект, т.к. его будет сопровождать другое окно. Для того что бы определить положен обьект или нет, нужно ещё читать дополнительные параметры этой ф-ции/обработчика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Если в дополнительные параметры приходит `AllowedEfects`  `DragDropEffects.None`, значит пользователь прекратил перетаскивание.

```
private void AssociatedObject_PreviewDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AllowedEffects == DragDropEffects.None)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```